# How can I use Joomla session from an external module?

Tags: php, joomla

I've created an external module for my website in Jooma. I need to check if the user is logged, so I tried to load the file **/libraries/import.php** in order to use `JFactory::getSession()` but it exists in some point.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Egidio

Comment: So you tried to load the *import.php*...is that being done correctly? Are you getting any errors from that? Are you getting any errors from any of your other code you're using? Can you provide a little more code snippets you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

External Module means pure php file outside joomla right ? or its a joomla module ?.
If it is external file like below.

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is when we are in the root
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
$mainframe->initialise();
$session     = JFactory::getSession();
$user = JFactory::getUser();

if($user->id > 0)
      echo "Logged In";
else
    echo "Not logged In";
```

Its joomla module like

```
 $user = JFactory::getUser();

    if($user->id > 0)
          echo "Logged In";
    else
        echo "Not logged In";
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Actually, I am logged in but I the JUser has ID equal to zero.

Comment: * *cough* * `&` * *cough* *

Comment: @Aegidius user id is 0 ?

Comment: @Lodder wht do you mean ?

Comment: In `$mainframe =& JFactory::` you don't need to use `&`. It can be removed

Comment: @Jobin Jose yes, the user ID is zero. But I'm logged in Jooma.

Comment: pls print the $user object echo "<pre/>"; print_r($user);

Comment: This means your user object is null ie, not logged in or framework is not yet loaded properly.Can you give the path of your module from your joomla installation?

Comment: @JobinJose my module is under the folder /business in the root directory.

Comment: if your external file is under another folder means you have to try define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(dirname(__FILE__))); instead of define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__) );//this is only when we are in the root Hope its worked :)